# Node/Express - How to send get request to check a status code

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, http-status-codes

I am trying to make a URL shortener. I need to take a given URL as a parameter and send a request to that URL just to get the status code. If status = 200, I know I've got a functioning URL, and I'll go ahead and add it to the DB and shorten it.

Problem is, when I make that request, the connection times out.

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors')
const nofavicon = require('express-no-favicons')
const Shortener = require('./shortener')
const app = express()

app.disable('x-powered-by')
app.use(cors())
app.use(nofavicon())
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'))

mongoose.connect(
   process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://heroku_x7hcc5zd:39c8i70697o7qrpjn4rd6kslch@ds123371.mlab.com:23371/heroku_x7hcc5zd'
)

app.get('/url/:urlParam(*)', (request, response) => {
  let urlParam = request.params.urlParam
  let urlRegEx = /[A-Za-z]+[://]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&;?#/.=]+/g

  if (urlRegEx.test(urlParam)) {
    let shortRandomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000).toString()
    // Shortener here refers to a mongoose Schema in external file
    let lmao = new Shortener({
      url: urlParam,
      urlmao: 'localhost:8080/lol/' + shortRandomNum,
    })

    // Request header from passed URL to verify legitimacy
    // Check statusCode and end request.
    app.head(urlParam, (req, res) => {
      let end = res.end
      // Override standard res.end function with custom function
      res.end = () => {
        if (res.statusCode == 200) {
          lmao.save((error) => {
            if (error) {
              response.send('Unable to write to collection')
            }
          })
          console.log('pass')
          response.json({lmao})
        }
      }
      res.end = end
      res.end()
    })

  } else {
    // If passed URL does not satisfy regEx, return error message.
    urlParam = 'unfunny url. http(s):// prefix required. check url and retry.'
    console.log('invalid url')

    response.json({
      url: urlParam,
    })
  }
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
console.log('live connection')
})
```

Most baffingly, the code shown here worked on Friday. Tested it last night, no dice. Any insight would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app.head(urlParam, [Function])` doesn't make a request to the url, it defines a new route on your application so that it responds to `HEAD`requests on that url.

To check if the URL is alive you need to use another package to make requests. One of my favourites is [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request). To use it simply replace `app.head` with `request` and add the `require('request')` to the top of your file.

Comment: Thanks a million. Had a little trouble at first since the package name 'request' was conflicting with the 'request' variable from the app.get() call.
In the unlikely case anybody else sees this and benefits from it.